# OSGI: Activate and Bind methods changes starting order after restarting the bundle

Tags: java, osgi, bundle

in my project I have an OSGI bundle. In this bundle I have an Activated method and a bind(to ConfigurationAdmin) method.

When I run the project for the first time the Activated method is called first, so i can initialize all the things I need, but if I stop the bundle and then start it again the bind method is called first and I have a nullpointer(because the initializations in Activate are not called yet).

The reference at the bind method is "cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC"

Why when started for the second time the order changes?

```
@Component(configurationPid = "ConsulService", immediate = true, service = ConsulService.class)
public class ConsulServiceImpl implements ConsulService {

private ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin;
private BundleContext context;
private Consul consul;

@Override
public AgentClient agentClient() {
    return consul.agentClient();
}

@Override
public KeyValueClient keyValueAgent() {
    return consul.keyValueClient();
}

@Activate
public void activate(BundleContext bundleContext) {
//this cause the nullpointer after the stop and the restarting of this bundle
//since this method is not called "consul" is null
    this.consul = Consul.builder().build();
    this.context = bundleContext;
}

...

@Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL, policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC, unbind = "unbindConfigurationAdmin")
public void bindConfigurationAdmin(final ConfigurationAdmin configurationAdmin) {
    this.configurationAdmin = configurationAdmin;
    // Here I have nullpointer because consul is not initializated 
    KeyValueClient keyValueAgent = keyValueAgent();
    ...
}
```

Comment: What bundle do you stop? The bundle with your component or the bundle that hosts the service you bind to?

Comment: Hi Christian, 
I stop the bundle with my component. 
ConfigurationAdmin is a service from OSGI

Comment: Sounds strange then.. can you show the relevant code of the component ?

Comment: I have edited my question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the binding method is called when the service is available. 
At the first start when the Activated method is called the configurationAdmin is not available yet, but when I stop the bundle and then restart it again the configurationAdmin is available and the bind is called before activated.

Answer (score 1):

Bind methods can be called *before* the activate method. In fact, bind methods *must* be called before the activate method for static references. Think of an activate method as a post-construct method. If you require your activate method to be your constructor, then use constructor injection which is supported in DS 1.4.

Comment: I am using the DS 1.3 and it seems to be not supported